# Android, Configuring click listener for frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout

as you can see in following screen shot of my program, the screen includes several frames and each frame has two image views and a text view.
I want another activity starts, when user clicks on a frame (or imageView or textView).

In code, I have written:

```
final FrameLayout frame01 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame01);
```

but when I add following code, program crashes!

```
frame01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Frame01 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

what should I do?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you post Logcat output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to comment the following line:

`Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Frame01 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Are you sure you have the current class name "Main.java"?

Comment: Oh, man you are right. I wrote in a wrong activity. I moved code to true activity and it works fine. Thanks and sorry for stupid mistake :(

Comment: No matter buddy.
A problem is always rock solid before solution and stupid mistake once we get a solution.
and it happened a lot of times with me.
:D